# How do you figure out if a vector field is conservative?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-fields

Specifically, if we are given a vector field $F(x,y,z)=(F_1(x,y,z),F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z))^T$, how do we know if $F$ is conservative? I.e. does there exists an $f$ such that $\nabla f=F$? I am aware of the curl and the second derivative methods, as well as the fact that that all line integrals must be path independent.

However, are there any other results or conditions that would also give me existence of a solution? Preferably a method that does not rely on $F_1,$ $F_2$, and $F_3$ having derivatives.

Comment: First, most of your tags are inappropriate. You are aware of all the methods. The topology of the region only enters if $F$ passes the curl test (without vanishing first cohomology or fundamental group, even vanishing curl tells you only that $F$ is locally conservative).

Comment: I guess I could comment that in a star-shaped region, you could just start solving for a potential function. That is, solve $\partial f/\partial x = F_1$ to get $f(x,y,z)=\int F_1\,dx + g(y,z)$, then solve $\partial f/\partial y = F_2$ to get $\partial g/\partial y$ and integrate it, etc. At the end, see if it works to give you a potential function.